# Dropdown Mvc Display Default Selected Item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in MVC, I would like to ask if you can teach me how to set/display the default item in the dropdown list?

in the Controller..

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
{
    EmployeeDBEntities o = new EmployeeDBEntities();
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e = o.Employees.Single(x => x.EMP_ID  == ID);
    ViewBag.Dept = o.uspDeptCbo().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.DEPT_ID.ToString() , Text=x.DEPARTMENT  }); 
    return View(e);
}
```

View

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("Dept",string.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DEPT_ID)
</div>
```

Comment: Use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DEPT_ID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Dept, string.Empty)` (then get rid of your awful use of `ViewBag` and do it correctly by using a view model)

Answer (score -2):

i got it!

in the controller..

```
enter code here

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
{
ViewBag.Dept = o.uspDeptCbo().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.DEPARTMENT, Value = x.DEPT_ID.ToString(), Selected = (x.DEPT_ID.ToString() == "3") }); 
}
```

in the view..

```
 <fieldset>
  @Html.DropDownList("Dept", string.Empty)
 </fieldset>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You clearly do not understand how MVC works - this will not bind correctly to your model.